# When to use Kelvin over Rankine and vice versa

Tags: temperature, units, conventions

Kelvin and Rankine are both used by scientists over Celsius and Fahrenheit to record heat, but are they both used interchangeably, dependant on the country or preference of an individual, or are there specific situations when one is better than the other? Is it common for people to change when one is more preferable than the other?

Comment: Where do they use Rankine? Just curious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kelvin is the SI unit. It is far more common than Rankine.

I cannot recall ever encountering Rankine temperature units, except in historical or humorously-backward contexts.

Note that these measure temperature, not heat. The SI and "imperial" measures of heat is are the joule and the BTU, respectively.

To avoid causing headaches, use SI for everything — please!